Can the Paradox of Phenomenal Judgement be resolved with a non-causal theory of knowledge?
In The Conscious Mind (Chalmers, 1996), David Chalmers presents the paradox of phenomenal judgement, a contradiction that arises from the dualism of consciousness and some empirical facts, and that some would claim is fatal to dualism. He frames it as follows:

The paradox is a consequence of the facts that:  (1) the physical domain is causally closed [empirical fact]  (2) judgements about consciousness are logically supervenient on the physical [from Chalmer's definition of judgements about consciousness]  (3) consciousness is not logically supervenient of the physical [i.e., dualism]; and  (4) we know we are conscious [1st person knowledge]  From premises (1) and (2) it follows that judgments about consciousness can be reductively explained. In combination with premise (3), this implies that consciousness is explanatorily irrelevant to our judgements, which lies in tension with premise (4).

(p. 183; line breaks/punctuation and brackets added by me). Two key terms are defined elsewhere:

judgements about consciousness (or phenomenal judgements) are "the various judgements in the vicinity of consciousness" after "any associated phenomenal quality [of the judgement] is subtracted" (pp. 173-74).
B-properties are logically supervenient on A-properties iff "for any logically possible world W that is A-indiscernible from our world, then the B-facts true of our world are true of W" (p. 40).
Also, he uses experience and conciousness interchangeably, and both refer to phenomenal consciousness rather than access consciousness.

The contradictions, then, is that "if experience plays no causal role in the formation of [phenomenal] judgements, then they cannot count as knowledge" (p. 193). This, Chalmers says, is based on a causal theory of knowledge - that for knowledge to count as knowledge, it must bear a causal relation to what it is knowledge about. Chalmers attempts to resolve the paradox by instead appealing to a non-causal theory of knowledge: he says our knowledge of our own experiences is justified because of some "more immediate relation" (p. 198) that is independent of the causal chain. He does little to elaborate on or explain this theory of knowledge ("many issues remain to be dealt with" [p. 199]; and I'm not sure I understand what little he does say about it).
This is where I get stuck. The idea of justified knowledge without causation certainly does not seem logically possible to me. But I can't think of a way to demonstrate that it isn't logically possible.
At first, it seems like a counterfactual analysis of causation could do this: if we didn't have experiences, we wouldn't know about them; therefore, our experiences cause our knowledge. But according to Chalmers, we would know that we were conscious even if we weren't, because our phenomenal judgements are logically supervenient on the physical organization of our brains (premise 2). Therefore, a counterfactual analysis of causation does not demonstrate that our knowledge of consciousness is caused by consciousness. (Perhaps we are equivocating on "knowledge" here? I'm not sure).
My question, then, is: Does Chalmers' solution to the paradox of phenomenal judgement succeed? Specifically, I'd be interested in an answer that either says yes and explains why my intuition (that knowledge without causation is impossible) is false; or says no, and identifies a flaw in Chalmers' solution; or references another author that has addressed this issue; or presents another solution to the paradox (without discarding premise 3) that renders Chalmers' solution unnecessary.

Causal theory of knowledge once led to what is called Benacerraf's dilemma for mathematical platonism: mathematical objects are causally inert abstractions, so how can we have knowledge of them that we do? "Today few epistemologists hold that the causal theory of knowledge is our best theory of knowledge. But it turns out that Benacerraf’s problem is remarkably robust under variation of epistemological theory." Our own consciousness is arguably 'closer' to us than mathematics so acausal access is perhaps more plausible.

@Conifold Or just reject mathematical platonism. The same "problem" arises when we ask how we know that Harry Potter played Quidditch. Was there a causal chain from Harry to us? No, because he's not real. There is little temptation to invoke "Harry Potter Platonism." We instead know Harry Potter played Quidditch because there is a causal chain from JK Rowling's statements that he played Quidditch, to us. And it is sufficient to know what an author canonically stated about their character, to know facts about the character.

Chalmers' intuition is that for:

(4) we know we are conscious [1st person knowledge]

to be true, then our judgment that we are conscious must occur in precisely those possible worlds that we are conscious. In other words, the judgment must reliably depend on whether or not we are conscious.
But if (1) and (2) are true, then our judgment that we are conscious depends only on physical facts, and if (3) is true, then there are possible worlds in which those physical facts lead to the judgment that we are not conscious, but in which we are indeed conscious.
So that stands in contradiction with (4). In other words, if (1), (2), and (3) are true, then the judgment that we are conscious is fully independent of whether we actually are conscious, and therefore we cannot call this judgment "knowledge."

My resolution to this problem is to accept (1) and (2) and (4), but reject (3). There is a causal chain connecting the fact of your consciousness to your judgment that you are conscious, because consciousness is a physical property. This physical property directly caused your brain to emit the statement that you are conscious. This physical property is identifiable with certain aspects of the patterns of neural activity that, in the neural account, caused you to emit the statement. "Your consciousness caused you to say 'I am conscious,'" and "Your neurons caused you to say 'I am conscious,'" are simply two ways of telling the same story.
All physical interactions have the nature of conscious experience; like Chalmers, I am a panpsychist.

+1, though I have a question. You seem to be using different ontological categories than Chalmers (at least those that he uses in this book), in that you include phenomenal properties in the physical domain. What Chalmers means by "physical" is what, as I understand it, you might call "physical modulo phenomenal properties." Using this language, would you still reject premise (3) ( "consciousness is not logically supervenient on the physical modulo phenomenal properties")? Would you then reject (1) ("the physical domain modulo phenomenal properties is causally closed")?

@Eonema I would say that "the physical modulo phenomenal properties" is empty, as all causal influence occurs via one system phenomenally perceiving, and thus reacting to, another. So I would have to stop using the word "physical" altogether if I chose that interpretation of the term. I find it more convenient to instead go on calling physical what is usually called physical.

@Eonema To put it another way: everything that happens, happens from some point of view.

Thank you, that answers my question. Seems I need to read more about panpsychism, maybe Chalmers' more recent work?
